# Retrieving a product of a specific category in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, relationship

I am having a Laravel project whereby I have created two tables(products and categories) and interlinked them through one to many relationship. One Category has many products. I have created a CRUD controller known as ProductsController and am storing images in a folder called images inside public in Laravel app.

The problem starts when I try to retrieve stored images of a specific category and display in view.
Please assist.

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');   
    }

}
```

**Product model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'desctiption' , 'size', 'category_id'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }


}
```

**ProductsController**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $formInput=$request->except('image');

       //validation
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'size'=>'required',
            'description' => 'required|min:12',
            'price'=>'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif|max:100'
        ]);

        //Instantiate a new Project called Product
        $product = new Product;

        //Add the products to the Object
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->size = $request->size;

        //Save all the items to the database
        $product->save();


        //image upload and save in folder in our app
        $image=$request->image;
        if($image){
            $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('images',$imageName);
            $formInput['image']=$imageName;
        }

        Session::flash('message' , $request->name . '&nbsp; has been successfully added');

        Product::create($formInput);
        return redirect()->route('product.create');
    }


     public function show($id)
        {

            $items = Category::find(6)->products()->where('images' , true)->get();

            return view('front.index', compact('items'));
        }
```

**Front.index view**

```
@foreach($items as $item)
        <img src="{{ url('images', $item->image) }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: did ur images stored in local folder and database

Comment: @RamAnji They are stored in public/images i Laravel app..

Comment: @Patwan check the detailed answer below

Comment: what about database?

Comment: All other data except images

Comment: @Patwan because you use  $formInput=$request->except('image'); and u save with this name..see bellow code it works..here both input and database name is image..remember it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead

```
Product::create($formInput);
```

something like

```
$product->image = $imageName; 
$product->save();
```

Comment: The code below saves the images in the local folder: $image=$request->image;
        if($image){
            $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('images',$imageName);
            $formInput['image']=$imageName;
        }

Comment: Yes and after moving images, you should save the image name to `image` field of related product. Create method will insert new row in database.

Comment: Ok, I have got your point, then how do I go about pulling the image os a specific category and display in the view

Comment: You did all right except this line 
Product::create($formInput);

Try after line 
$formInput['image']=$imageName; to add 
$product->image = $imageName;
And instead Product::create($formInput); Move lines 
//Save all the items to the database
$product->save();

Comment: ** This way **    `
        $image=$request->image;
        if($image){
            $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('images',$imageName);
            $formInput['image']=$imageName;
            $product->image = $imageName;
        }
        $product = new Product;

        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->size = $request->size;`

Comment: Also add image field to $fillable array in your Product model

Comment: Does this code store the image name in the database cause am a bit confused:about its role   $product->image = $imageName;

Comment: $product->image = $imageName; // this line will set image name in field `image` in `products` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Leonid,,, Would you mind checking the code inside the show function I posted and tell me if am correct,,, Am a bit new to Laravel thats why am unsure of CRUD functions..

Comment: If field in products table called `image` and it has NULL value by default so query in show function should be 
$items = Category::find(6)->products()->whereNotNull('image')->get();

Comment: Hello Leonid,, hope you you don.t mind about my late question,,, I tried everything out and it worked fine,,, now when I call the variable $items in the view using foeach loop from the Productscontroller I get an error undefined variable. The view has a different controller. Was wondering if it is possible to pass a variable from a different controller to the view of another controller? Also is it possible to pull data from a database without using CRUD show and edit methods.

Comment: Actually I mean how to pass a variable from one controller to another controller by using a session

Comment: If you want to use session please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session. But if you want to set one variable in different views I recoment you to use Service Providers and View Composers https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers

Answer (score 1):

strore image in local folder

```
$imageNames = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $request->image->move(public_path('uploads'), $imageNames);
```

first change;Product::create($formInput);to

```
$oroduct=new Product;
$product->image= $imageName;
```

and @foreach($items as $item)
        image) }}">
@endforeach to

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/uploads/'.$items->image) }}"/>
```

upload is local folder where u save the images..in ur case may be it different

Answer (score 0):

First check if the Images are available under `/public/images` folder
If so, try to access them this way:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image) }}">
```

**Note:**

If the image isn't persisted in the database, that because you're using Product::create and not including the image in the $fillable array, so it can't be mass assigned !

**Note2 :**

You can upload the images to the public folder so they can be accessed from the public directory using this function I created, you can call it after your validation with 2 parameters ***(the image file from the request and relative path from public folder to where you want to save it)*** and it will return the filename that you can persist in the database:

```
public function upload_image($request['image'], $folder='images'){
  $filename = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $image->move(public_path($folder), $filename);
  return $filename;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Still does not work, am really wondering if images of the specific category are being found cause all other data is stored in the database while images are stored in the app...

Comment: inside your database, whats in the 'images' column? I guess you'll find there the Image name, if not try to add 'image' to $fillable and try persisting the values again, and can you find images inside /public/images ?  @Patwan

Comment: because like you know the only thing that we save in the database is the filename and we save the image in the public folder so we can access it from there

Comment: Yah, I can find the images in the public folder after uploading... Let me try the code you posted, will let you know incase of any issue

Comment: Just some clarification, I cant understand what the function does cause if it was intended for storing images in the public folder, the images are already being stored in the folder by the code I posted, problem comes when I retrieve images of a specific category and display to view

Comment: Yes the fonctions store the images, its a better way to do it (just I gave you a better improved way) and if the images are exists and not retrieved then that's weird cuz the way i showed above should do it, Try to access it like that http://your-url/public/images/(name of an image from database)

Comment: Would you mind checking the code I posted in store function, what do you think about it,, is it the correct way to fetch image of a specific id,,,Am a bit new to Laravel...

Comment: You're not saving the image to the database, you have to save it, add a column called image, and then add it to the fillable array and then save it with product! and then you can access it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help...Regards

Comment: @Patwan you can select the answer or upvote it, thanks